# PHP/mySQL: mysql_query with SELECT, FROM, and WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause, fetch

I am trying to set `$nextPageID` and `$nextPageTitle` with the following code. Unfortunately they are not getting set.

```
$pageCategoryID = 1;
$nextPageOrder = 2;

$fetchedNextPageData = mysql_query("
  SELECT pageID, pageCategoryID, 'order', title 
  FROM pages 
  WHERE pageCategoryID='$pageCategoryID' AND 'order'='$nextPageOrder'
") or die(mysql_error());

            while ($nextPageArray = mysql_fetch_array($fetchedNextPageData)) {
                $nextPageID = $nextPageArray['pageID'];
                $nextPageTitle = $nextPageArray['title'];
            }
```

My table `pages` contains a row with pageID = 2, pageCategoryID = 1, order = 2, title = Next Page, plus 4 other columns with data I don't need for this query.

This code has been simplified for testing purposes. It will be sanitized after I get it working.

Any thoughts on what I can do to get this bit of code working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget about PHP right now. This is your SQL query:

```
SELECT pageID, pageCategoryID, 'order', title 
FROM pages 
WHERE pageCategoryID='1' AND 'order'='2'
```

In SQL, as in many other languages, you use quotes to type literal strings. Since the `'order'` string will never equal the `'1`' string, your query will always return zero rows, no matter the other values.

If `order` is a column name, you cannot single-quote it.

Now, given that `ORDER` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), you'll have to use backticks around it. You can also type integers as integers (there's no need to quote them):

```
SELECT pageID, pageCategoryID, `order`, title 
FROM pages 
WHERE pageCategoryID=1 AND `order`=2
```

Answer (score 5):

you are overwriting the variable for each record, maybe create an array like

```
 $data = array();
 while ($nextPageArray = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetchedNextPageData)) {
   $data[] = array('id' => $nextPageArray['pageID'], 
            'title' => $nextPageArray['title']);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. This did not fix the primary issue of needing to use backticks and removing some of the single quotes. Personally I find the way you wrote this to require a lot more code and not be as clear. However, I'm still new to PHP and mySQL and maybe in time I'll see it your way.

Answer (score 1):

In the WHERE clause of your query try removing the quotes around order and use back ticks instead like this:

```
`order`='$nextPageOrder'
```

And try to avoid using keywords for table/column names! Been there.

Comment: I have to have the quotes around `order` or else I get an error. I think because it reads it as `order` as in `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @MarkRummel you then need backticks, not quotes

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The backticks are correct, but I had to remove the single quotes to get it to work.